# what will happen when two records are duplicate on PK in the batch insert with "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am working with java + mysql. I try to have a bulk insert with "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in the script to do update if PK is duplicate. I understand that the existing record will be updated if the inserting row has the same PK as the existing record. However, what if there are two inserted rows having the same PK? For example, in my insert sql script it is like

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?') on duplicate key update col1=?, col2=?, col3=?
```

where col1 is the PK of the table1. Now, let's say my insert records are

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3), (val1, val4, val5)
```

Will it fail or it will have (val1, val4, val5) in the table? Thanks.

Comment: could you not simply run a test with some garbage data?

Comment: It seems an easy enough thing to test.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I simply tested with below code

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO people (name, age)
    VALUES
    ('Helen', 24),
    ('Katrina', 21),
    ('Helen', 22),
    ('Hui Ling', 25),
    ('Yumie', 29)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name = VALUES(name),
    age = VALUES(age);
```

Four rows were inserted and `('Helen', 22)` was the one.